# ImageScaleToFit() with percentages

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I want to scale an image using a scale amount value passed to it from a FORM. The thing is that I'm getting syntax errors.

I have a hidden input in my form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="scale" value="0.16"/>
```

In my page that processes the image I want it to do this:

```
<cfset ImageScaleToFit(MyImg, ARGUMENTS.SCALE%, "", "highestQuality")/>
```

I know the above cfml is not correct but I don't understand how to convert the scale value into a percentage that ColdFusion can work with. In this case, 0.16 means I want the image to be 16% of the original size. So I'm reducing it by 84%.  If the scale was 3.5 then I need to increase the size of the image by 350%.

1. How do I pass the value from the input into the ImageScaleToFit() function. Passing it in as above using `ARGUMENTS.Scale%` is giving me syntax errors. For some reason its not being compiled to `0.16%`
2. How do I convert the actual scale value e.g. `0.16` so that it ends up being a correct percentage that ColdFusion can work with to correctly scale the image either up or down?

Comment: You would need to calculate the value in pixels and pass that as the second argument

Comment: @MattBusche is correct, looking at the documentation, it doesn't accept a percentage value.  you'll need to work out what 16% of the original size image is in pixels on width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ImageScaleToFit`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ImageScaleToFit) is looking for the value in pixels. You need to take the original image width and multiple that by your scale value

```
<cfset ImageScaleToFit(MyImg, ARGUMENTS.SCALE * originalImageWidth, "", "highestQuality")/>
```

Comment: Would it better to use the ImageResize() function instead then?

Comment: `ImageResize` requires you calculate the width and height, so it would be more work.

Comment: I tried it, using your solution with ImageReszie() instead and it seems to work the same. It did take a little bit longer but not sure why. But this has solved my issue so thank you very much Matt! Voted as answer.